# How to get sales Amount diff between previous and next month including other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table where I am having sales data for each day for each country and city

| Date | Country | City | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3/1/2023 | India | Hyderabad | 800 |
| 3/2/2023 | India | Hyderabad | 300 |
| 3/3/2023 | India | Hyderabad | 500 |
| 4/1/2023 | USA | Newyork | 300 |
| 4/2/2023 | USA | Newyork | 500 |
| 4/3/2023 | USA | Newyork | 200 |
| 5/1/2023 | Australia | Perth | 100 |
| 5/2/2023 | Australia | Perth | 400 |
| 5/3/2023 | Australia | Perth | 400 |

Expected Output:

| Date | Country | City | Sales | Diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5/1/2023 | Australia | Perth | 900 | 100 |
| 4/1/2023 | USA | Newyork | 1000 | 600 |
| 3/1/2023 | India | Hyderabad | 1600 | 0 |

I created the below query to get sales sum for each month and I need to calculate difference between previous month and next month But not getting the result when I have more than one country or state for same dates.
Like lets say If I take country=India and I am getting expected result but If I take all countries or cities Its not coming.

```
select *, LAG(Sales, 1, Sales) OVER (ORDER BY date, Country, State) - Sales AS Diff
from (
  select min(date) as date,Country,State,sum(Sales) as Sales
  from SalesTable )
  group by YEAR(date), MONTH(date),Country,State
) as s
order by date desc
```

Could anyone please help on this

Comment: [No issue in your query](https://dbfiddle.uk/GQuTs3DA), if the expected output is the one you're showing.

Answer (score 0):

When asking questions like this it's very helpful to provide easily reproducible DDL/DML, something like this:

```
DECLARE @SalesTable TABLE (Date DATE,   Country NVARCHAR(50),   City NVARCHAR(50),  Sales DECIMAL(10,2));
INSERT INTO @SalesTable (Date, Country, City, Sales) VALUES
('1/3/2023', 'India     ', 'Hyderabad   ', 800),
('2/3/2023', 'India     ', 'Hyderabad   ', 300),
('3/3/2023', 'India     ', 'Hyderabad   ', 500),
('1/4/2023', 'USA       ', 'Newyork     ', 300),
('2/4/2023', 'USA       ', 'Newyork     ', 500),
('3/4/2023', 'USA       ', 'Newyork     ', 200),
('1/5/2023', 'Australia ', 'Perth       ', 100),
('2/5/2023', 'Australia ', 'Perth       ', 400),
('3/5/2023', 'Australia ', 'Perth       ', 400);
```

Using this, we can take a look at the `LAG` windowed function:

```
SELECT *, Sales-COALESCE(LAG(Sales,1) OVER (PARTITION BY Country, City ORDER BY Date),0) AS Difference, LAG(Sales,1) OVER (PARTITION BY Country, City ORDER BY Date) AS LastMonthSales 
  FROM @SalesTable
```

| Date | Country | City | Sales | Difference | LastMonthSales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-05 | Australia | Perth | 100.00 | 100.00 |  |
| 2023-02-05 | Australia | Perth | 400.00 | 300.00 | 100.00 |
| 2023-03-05 | Australia | Perth | 400.00 | 0.00 | 400.00 |
| 2023-01-03 | India | Hyderabad | 800.00 | 800.00 |  |
| 2023-02-03 | India | Hyderabad | 300.00 | -500.00 | 800.00 |
| 2023-03-03 | India | Hyderabad | 500.00 | 200.00 | 300.00 |
| 2023-01-04 | USA | Newyork | 300.00 | 300.00 |  |
| 2023-02-04 | USA | Newyork | 500.00 | 200.00 | 300.00 |
| 2023-03-04 | USA | Newyork | 200.00 | -300.00 | 500.00 |

`LAG` takes two parameters, the name of the column and the number of rows to go back. It works over a window, defined in the OVER. In this case, we want to partition by country and city, and order by date.

Comment: Hi @Patrick Hurst,

This is working fine.But I need to show Difference as 0 if there is no last month values. In my case I need to show 0 for Difference in March month as there is no previous month sales.And also I need to aggrigate this by each month

Comment: Your example data appears to have been pre-aggregated by month. You could likely use a sub query, and apply the same method to that data set. As for returning 0 when there was no previous month, you could probably use a case expression to handle that, though it feels wrong, as there was effectively 0 sales in the non-existent month.